# How to display data from sql server with java [android studio]

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql-server

I wish to display some data from my SQL server into my application.

Let me explain throw an example what have i done until now, and please tell me how should i go on with my work:

(1) I have a database named: 'DB1'
(2) In my database i have table named 'users':

```
Id, Name, LastName
1   Dave  Stone
2   Rose  Mary
3   Gray  Lone
```

(3) I created 3 php files: 1/ config.php (sets up my database log in information like password...)
2/ DBConnection.php : `

```
// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'Config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    // return database handler
    return $this->conn;
}
}

?>
```

3/ GetUsers.php which i dont know how should i write it - **this would be the code which will echo whatever i want from the table.**

(4) Inside my android studio project i have a MainActivity.java and i want to get all the LastNames of all the users in the database and do whatever with them... like print them into a text box it doesn't really matter (let's say i don't know how many users I have).

**I need some one to help me get stages (3)3/ + (4) done / explained.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a very _broad_ question. Therefore, you are running the risk that it is going to be flagged as _too broad_ and will be closed. In the future try to write questions that are not so broad. Nevertheless, you probably should look into something called REST web service. Your PHP "app" could expose the user data you are looking for as a REST service. This service will "echo" the data as JSON. Your Android app then needs to consume this JSON. There are a _lot_ of examples for something like this.

Comment: @Jens Thank's Jens, but I searched for a solution for this question and unfortunately I didn't manage to find some answers, furthermore my real problem is much bigger and complicated than this question but i tried to simplify it as much as i could... sadly it turn out to be too "broad" for you but I'm sure that this question (and hopefully a full answer) will help a lot of people.

Comment: It is not just too broad for me. Those are the rules of Stack Overflow. You can read about the rules at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Here is an example for something you could use to achieve your goal: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean is a good method to retrieve and set values from app to database, the best and most prominent way is using basic REST services that convert your db values to JSON then you load the json using your api key as authentication, it might sound really stressful but is in fact very easy and flexible to implement, the only way you can directly set and get db values on android is using sqlite (android local inbuilt db)

The best tutorial and major explanation for exactly what you want to achieve is here

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Then this one for further works
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

It covers how you make a rest service yourself